# Regex Jersey Rest Service

Tags: regex, jersey

I have the following regex in jersey, that works:

```
/artist_{artistUID: [1-9][0-9]*}
```

however, if i do

```
/{artistUID: [artist_][1-9][0-9]*}
```

it does not, what i do not understand how the regexes are being build and do not find any good documentation for it. What i want to do is something like this:

```
/{artistUID: ([uartist_]|[artist_])[1-9][0-9]*}
```

to recognize terms like "artist_123" and "uartist_123" and store them in the artistUID value.

Comment: I think you misuse the character class here (`[...]` match 1 single character). Try `/{artistUID: (uartist|artist)_[1-9][0-9]*}`.

Comment: Don't forget you always have an option to split your single endpoint into two of them `/artistUID/{uartist_[1-9][0-9]*}` and `/artistUID/{artist_[1-9][0-9]*}` for simplify your problem

Comment: Thanks @wiktor-stribiżew , the `/{artistUID: (uartist|artist)_[1-9][0-9]*}` part worked like it should =) If you repost as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: @Simons0n: Thank you for feedback, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *alternation group* (`(...|...)`) rather than a  characrter class `[...]` (that matches 1 single character defined inside it).

Use

```
/{artistUID: (uartist|artist)_[1-9][0-9]*}
```

Or to make it shorter, use a `?` quantifier after `u` to make it optional:

```
/{artistUID: u?artist_[1-9][0-9]*}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG1dZ4/1)